# How to set a Marker on UIImage in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, marker

I am developing an application that display an image of my building.
The user should be able to click on the image and set a pin on the tapped location (CGPoint). The pin should remain on this location of the image even if I zoom in and out unless I clear all the pins(Similar to a pin on the map).

I am trying to search for a solution but all I can find on forums is how to set Pins to a map.
How can I achieve my goal? It has been a while trying to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: where you want to set marker?

Comment: User will be able to click on the image (which represents the floor map) and the marker should be set on the point where the user tapped.